# Why is my linq alias out of scope?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to better understand more complex linq statements. And thanks to a few articles on the web I am coming around. One thing I don't understand is why my query alias is out of context on this statement:

```
(from query in _context.WebQueries
            select query).Where((from qry in _context.WebQueries
                join qg in _context.WebQueryGroups on qry.QueryKey equals qg.QueryKey
                where qg.QueryGroupNameKey == key
                                              //This is out of scope
                select qry.QueryKey).Contains(query.QueryKey));
                                    //if you replaced it with this same problem
                                    .Contains(qry.QueryKey));
```

I know that I can use an anonymous object call and gain the results I want. I will just have to iterate the object and pull out the List that I want:

```
(from query in _context.WebQueries
         select new {query, key = query.QueryKey})
         .Where(q => !(from qry in _context.WebQueries
                join qg in _context.WebQueryGroups on qry.QueryKey equals qg.QueryKey
                where qg.QueryGroupNameKey == key
                select qry.QueryKey).Contains(q.key));
```

That returns an object with the list I want and the int that I want to reference later in the query.

Why are both query and qry out of scope though? I would much rather just return the linq statement in my method instead of having to parse an object to get the list to return. An article discussing this issue would be great.

Comment: In the first codeblock, what is `request`?

Comment: an object passed into the method I'll fix that

Comment: What an ugly medley of query/method syntax :/

Comment: @BartoszKP as I mentioned I am still trying to learn better ways to write linq statements

Comment: Any reason you're making unnecesarily complicated queries? This is a good starting point.http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @Rodrigo I am rewriting a VB.NET app. I am pretty much copying what they are doing and converting it into C# code. I am not very fluent with linq so I am still working on optimizing the queries

Comment: Regarding over-complicated queries: in particular, this is weird: `from query in _context.WebQueries select query` This is called a "degenerate query" because it is the query that does nothing at all; it just gives you the items that are in the collection. You might as well have just said `_context.WebQueries` and skipped the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is an answer that solves the underlying problem and makes the query work, the actual question isn't answered yet. The answer to the question why the variables are out of scope will probably help you understand LINQ better.

The statement...

```
from query in _context.WebQueries select query
```

can be rewritten as:

```
_context.WebQueries.Select(query => query)
```

(the part `.Select(query => query)` is redundant, but I leave it here for sake of the explanation)

this statement can be rewritten as a lambda expression with a method body:

```
WebQueries.Select(query => { return query; })
```

(I'll explain later why I don't use `_context.WebQueries` anymore)

this can be rewritten as an expression with an anonymous method:

```
WebQueries.Select(delegate(WebQuery query) { return query; })
```

and this can be rewritten into an expression using a named method:

```
WebQueries.Select(ReturnArg)
```

where `ReturnArg` is this method:

```
WebQuery ReturnArg(WebQuery query)
{
    return query;
}
```

This is C# history in reverse order: we used to have named methods and delegates only. Later, in order to implement LINQ and other features, anonymous methods and lambda expressions were introduced. But the thing to note here is that under the hood, for the compiler, method syntax still applies, so the lambda expression `query => query` is nothing but a method having a parameter that is named `query`. As with all methods, *the parameter is scoped to the method body*.

In LINQ terminology, this parameter is called *range variable*, because it will serve as a reference to each successive element in the query.

In short: the range variable is scoped to the LINQ statement in which it is defined. `(from query in _context.WebQueries select query)` is one LINQ statement. The subsequent `Where` is a new LINQ statement.

The reason why I stopped using `_context.WebQueries` is that EF doesn't accept lambda expressions with method body. That is because the method body silently turns the parameter of the `Where` method from an expression into a `Func`, and EF only accepts expressions. In fact, the whole statement is never executed in CLR, but translated into SQL and executed by the database engine. However, for the C# compiler the correctness rules still apply. A range variable is a range variable, irrespective of what it's going to be used for.

Answer (score 7):

I notice you did not get an answer to your specific question, which is as I understand it "what are the scoping rules in queries?"

First off, let's carefully define "scope". The scope of an entity is a region of program text in which a particular entity can be referred to by an unqualified name.

The key to understanding range variable scope is in understanding how queries are translated by the compiler. It is a *syntactic* translation. When you say:

```
from r in s where t select u
```

that is translated syntactically by the compiler into:

```
((s).Where(r => t)).Select(r => u)
```

In the translated version there are *two* `r`s, both lambda formal parameters, and the regular scoping rules for lambdas apply; each is in scope only for the body of the lambda.

So now you know why you cannot use a range variable outside of a query; that range variable is actually the formal parameter of one or more lambdas, and so is only valid in what is going to be the bodies of those lambdas.

You can learn the rest of the rules by reading the C# specification section on query translation. I note that the rules for "transparent identifier" queries have tricky scoping, so read that section carefully.  I've been meaning to write a blog article on that.

UPDATE: I got around to writing that blog entry; you can read it here:

http://ericlippert.com/2014/07/31/transparent-identifiers-part-one/

http://ericlippert.com/2014/08/01/transparent-identifiers-part-two/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but this does the same thing:

```
(from query in _context.WebQueries
from qry in _context.WebQueries
join qg in _context.WebQueryGroups on qry.QueryKey equals qg.QueryKey
where qg.QueryGroupNameKey == request.Key
where qry.QueryKey == query.QueryKey
select query).Distinct();
```

However, this looks really strange. <strike>The join doesn't serve any function, for example.</strike>

Why not this?

```
from query in _context.WebQueries
join qg in _context.WebQueryGroups on query.QueryKey equals qg.QueryKey
where qg.QueryGroupNameKey == request.Key
select query
```

Comment: The join verifies that the result returned is also in the WebQueryGroups object as well correct? based on: where qg.QueryGroupNameKey == request.Key

Comment: Okay I see from this I need to order the queries better. It may also help me to optimize them better.

Comment: @Robert: I edited the response. I think you can simplify it further.

Comment: Now that I see how to better organize the queries I am rewriting I think I can do similar things like your cleaned up example.